# Referring to someone on temporary leave from their job

Tags: single-word-requests

How do I refer to someone who is on temporary leave from their job?  For example, we use *acting* for when someone is filling the role of said person (acting manager, etc.) or for someone who is filling a role temporarily.

Comment: In the U.S., simply saying someone is on *temporary leave* should be adequate, regardless of whether the reason is maternity/paternity, military duty, jury duty, illness, sabbatical, disciplinary suspension, or other "personal time."

Answer (score 1):

A word you could use for a temporary leave from a job is `Sabbatical`:

`A period of time during which someone does not work at his or her regular job and is able to rest, travel, do research, etc.` (Merriam-Webster Dictionary)

You would say something like: `My Professor is on a sabbatical this year.`

Comment: +1 I think [hiatus](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hiatus) would be an acceptable synonym, but I prefer your term.

Answer (score 1):

**Hiatus** immediately spring to mind (already suggested in comments by *Lumberjack*). It is a good, general purpose word to refer to a gap in an activity, such as work, hobby, etc.:

> a break or interruption in an activity

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hiatus))

You could say a person on a temporary leave is **on hiatus**.

The word is marked *formal* in Longman Dictionary, but bloggers and musicians often use it when they take a break from what they do.

Answer (score 0):

The word is ***furlough***, defined by the OED as:

> a. Leave of absence, esp. a permit or licence given to a soldier (or
>   more rarely, an official) to be absent from duty for a stated time.

It is not a word which is in regular currency. The more modern expression would be to say that the person was ***on leave of absence***.

Comment: In the US, *furlough* is often used for a forced absence without pay when a company/agency is trying to save money.

Comment: That sense is recorded by the OED in its list of draft additions 2015.  ***U.S. An instance of suspending an employee from work temporarily, typically without pay.***

Answer (score 0):

In the U.S. Military, a person is granted 4 weeks of "leave" a year and requests a "leave of absence" to be approved before going on "leave".  When asked "Where is he?" The reply is "he's on leave".